# Bulk removing future-dated e-mail from Yahoo! account

Tags: spam-prevention, yahoo-mail

My Yahoo! email account gets a lot of e-mails "from the future" (i.e. spam) that has the sent date in year 2038.

How do I easily remove these kind of e-mails? (there are several thousand of them and using the web interface will probably take forever).

Comment: This future dating is probably related to the [Unix year 2038 problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2038_problem).  It is possible that the mail header was spoofed in such a manner that resulted in an invalid date being used.

Comment: I fixed the title to clarify you're using Yahoo. I guess it doesn't have IMAP which would have made the thing a lot easier.

Answer (score 3):

In Yahoo! Mail *Classic* you have the advanced search options (just click search without entering any criteria in the search box to get the advanced options page). From there you can search for all emails after a certain date (ie. a date in the future). In the search results you can select them all and mark as spam / move to trash etc.

However, I don't see how you can get to the same advanced search options in the New Mail interface? You must initially search for *something* in order to get the "Narrow Results" options on the right of the page (for me there is no Advanced Search link at the bottom as is [mentioned in the help pages](http://help.yahoo.com/tutorials/mmail/mmail/mm_search5.html)). You can then pick the year (2038, if there are emails in the search results from that year) then select all the results and flag as spam / move to trash etc. as you would for Mail Classic.